# Парсинг динамического контента (который загружается спустя ~5 секунд)

Tags: javascript, ajax, веб-скрейпинг

Всем привет, нужен парсер, который парсит динамический контент. Я имею в виду сайты, на которых основной контент выводится спустя 3-5 секунд после загрузки самой страницы. То есть, мы указываем ссылку на сайт, а парсер парсит сайт не с начала загрузки, а уже через 5-10 секунд, когда весь контент уже загрузился. То есть, парсинг с интервалом. Надеюсь, вы меня поняли. Скорее всего, тут нужно задействовать PhantomJS или SlimerJS, либо что-то другое, что работает на javascript. Если нет, поправьте меня. Буду благодарен коду/ссылке/видео, главное - решить проблему.

Comment: Лучше использовать nightmare или SlimerJS

Answer (score 1):

Думаю Фантом это лучшее из решений, в тонкой настройке есть разные таймауты и тд. Дальше только ваша фантазия + документация http://phantomjs.org/documentation/

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();

page.open('http://phantomjs.org', function (status) {
  var content = page.content;
  console.log('Content: ' + content);
  phantom.exit();
});
```

Comment: в документации ничего не понял. нужно вставить этот код в phantomjs.exe? а "webpage" заменить на нужный файл? и как посмотреть в браузере результат кода?

Comment: поставить node js, установить npm, а именно webpage и запустить тем же node js. Фантом это консольный браузер.